# Mapping two columns into one column in Athena

Tags: sql, case, presto, amazon-athena, sql-null

I have data in the Athena something like this:

```
| shop_id  | date        | provider | provider_new |  sales
| 123      | 2020-06-01  |     X    |              |   100
| 124      | 2020-07-01  |     Y    |              |   200
| 125      | 2020-08-01  |          |      Z       |   300
| 126      | 2020-09-01  |          |      T       |   400
```

However, the table owner changed the `provider` to `provider_new`. Thus, after 2020-08-01 the provider returns to NULL. Here is my query:

```
SELECT date,
         shop_id,
             
    CASE
    WHEN provider = 'X' THEN
    'X'
    WHEN provider = 'Y' THEN
    'Y'
    WHEN provider LIKE 'Z%' THEN
    'Z'
    WHEN provider LIKE 'T%' THEN
    'T'
    ELSE 'M'
    END AS provider_group,
         SUM(sales) AS sales
FROM X
GROUP BY  1, 2
```

How can I map these two columns to one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want `coalesce()`?

```
coalesce(provider, provider_new)
```

`coalesce()` returns the first non-`null` value of the arguments it is given.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Where to add it to my query? @GMB

Comment: @datazang: you can just replace every occurence of `provider` with `coalesce(provider, provider_new)`.